# Can I select two periods of time at the same time using Dataframe.between_time function?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a Dataframe like this.

[image]

And I would like to select data within 9:30-11:30 and 13:00-15:00 everyday. However, using DataFrame.between_time function, I can only select one period of data.

The method I'm using now is select two period of data separately and concat the two dataframe I got, then reorder the index. However, I am curious that are there any way I can select two period of data at the same time?

Thanks for your time.

https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.between_time.html

Comment: add your input data in dataframe not in screenshot, and show us your expected output

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`DatetimeIndex.indexer_between_time`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DatetimeIndex.indexer_between_time.html) for positions of matched times for both ranges, join together with sorting by [`numpy.union1d`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.union1d.html) and last select rows by [`DataFrame.iloc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.iloc.html):

```
rng = pd.date_range('2017-04-03', periods=100, freq='30Min')
df = pd.DataFrame({'a': range(100)}, index=rng)  
print (df.head())
                     a
2017-04-03 00:00:00  0
2017-04-03 00:30:00  1
2017-04-03 01:00:00  2
2017-04-03 01:30:00  3
2017-04-03 02:00:00  4

idx1 = df.index.indexer_between_time('9:30', '11:30')
idx2 = df.index.indexer_between_time('13:00', '15:00')

df = df.iloc[np.union1d(idx1,idx2)]
```

---

```
print (df)

                      a
2017-04-03 09:30:00  19
2017-04-03 10:00:00  20
2017-04-03 10:30:00  21
2017-04-03 11:00:00  22
2017-04-03 11:30:00  23
2017-04-03 13:00:00  26
2017-04-03 13:30:00  27
2017-04-03 14:00:00  28
2017-04-03 14:30:00  29
2017-04-03 15:00:00  30
2017-04-04 09:30:00  67
2017-04-04 10:00:00  68
2017-04-04 10:30:00  69
2017-04-04 11:00:00  70
2017-04-04 11:30:00  71
2017-04-04 13:00:00  74
2017-04-04 13:30:00  75
2017-04-04 14:00:00  76
2017-04-04 14:30:00  77
2017-04-04 15:00:00  78
```